# React.JS, how to edit the response of a first API call with data from a second API call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I need to display some data in my component, unfortunately the first call to my API returns just part of the information I want to display, plus some IDs. I need another call on those IDs to retrieve other meaningful data. The first call is wrapped in a useEffect() React.js function:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
        try {
          const { data } = await fetchContext.authAxios.get(
            '/myapi/' + auth.authState.id
      );

    setData(data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
getData();
}, [fetchContext]);
```

And returns an array of objects, each object representing an appointment for a given Employee, as follows:

```
[
    {
        "appointmentID": 1,
        "employeeID": 1,
        "customerID": 1,
        "appointmentTime": "11:30",
        "confirmed": true
    },
... many more appointments
]
```

Now I would like to retrieve information about the customer as well, like name, telephone number etc. I tried setting up another method like `getData()` that would return the piece of information I needed as I looped through the various appointment to display them as rows of a table, but I learned the hard way that functions called in the render methods should not have any side-effects. What is the best approach to make another API call, replacing each "customerID" with an object that stores the ID of the customer + other data?

[Below the approach I've tried, returns an [Object Promise]]

```
const AppointmentElements = () => {
    
//Loop through each Appointment to create a single row
    var output = Object.values(data).map((i) =>
                <Appointment 
                    key={i['appointmentID'].toString()} 
                    employee={i["employeeID"]} //returned a [Object premise]
                    customer={getEmployeeData((i['doctorID']))} //return a [Object Promise]
                    time={index['appointmentTime']} 
                    confirmed = {i['confirmed']}
                /> 
        
    );
        return output;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you yourself mentioned functions called in the render methods should not have any side-effects, you shouldn't be calling the `getEmployeeData` function inside render.

What you can do is, inside the same `useEffect` and same `getData` where you are calling the first api, call the second api as well, nested within the first api call and put the complete data in a state variable. Then inside the render method, loop through this complete data instead of the data just from the first api.

Let me know if you need help in calling the second api in getData, I would help you with the code.

### Update (added the code)

Your `useEffect` should look something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await fetchContext.authAxios.get('/myapi/' + auth.authState.id);
            const updatedData = data.map(value => {
                    const { data } = await fetchContext.authAxios.get('/mySecondApi/?customerId=' + value.customerID);
                    // please make necessary changes to the api call
                    return {
                        ...value, // de-structuring
                        customerID: data
                        // as you asked customer data should replace the customerID field
                    }
                }
            );
            setData(updatedData); // this data would contain the other details of customer in it's customerID field, along with all other fields returned by your first api call
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
    getData();
}, [fetchContext]);
```

This is assuming that you have an api which accepts only one customer ID at a time.

---

If you have a better api which accepts a list of customer IDs, then the above code can be modified to:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await fetchContext.authAxios.get('/myapi/' + auth.authState.id);
            const customerIdList = data.map(value => value.customerID);
            // this fetches list of all customer details in one go
            const customersDetails = (await fetchContext.authAxios.post('/mySecondApi/', {customerIdList})).data;
            // please make necessary changes to the api call
            const updatedData = data.map(value => {
                   // filtering the particular customer's detail and updating the data from first api call
                   const customerDetails = customersDetails.filter(c => c.customerID === value.customerID)[0];
                    
                    return {
                        ...value, // de-structuring
                        customerID: customerDetails
                        // as you asked customer data should replace the customerID field
                    }
                }
            );
            setData(updatedData); // this data would contain the other details of customer in it's customerID field, along with all other fields returned by your first api call
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
    getData();
}, [fetchContext]);
```

This will reduce the number of network calls and generally preferred way, if your api supports this.

Comment: Hello @Shubhaw, yes I included the "bad example", as I hope would help the community.  The problem with the code right now is actually making the second call and put the complete data in the state variable.

Comment: @WebStormer I have updated my answer with the code. The first code makes multiple calls to the second api to fetch customer details one at a time. If your api supports fetching multiple customer data in one go, you can use the second approach.

Comment: I get the following compile error on the second "await": Unexpected reserved word 'await'. The reason is because the async keyword is missing just before the "value" variable